# "After power is switched on router" - preposition or a part of the verb?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

In the manual of my router, I have found this sentence. I am quite unsure as to what it means and if it is correct

> After power is switched on router XYZ starts internal wifi network.

Comment: This manual was obviously not written by a native English speaker. One can only guess at what was intended. I wouldn't guess.  Try to look for readable documentation, perhaps on the web.

Comment: There is a comma missing after "on".  (And a few other minor issues.)

Answer (score 1):

Is this an accurate description of what happens when you flip the switch:  "After [the] power is turned on, [then] Router XYZ starts [the] internal wifi network"?

If so, then "on" is an adverb of position, telling where the switch is set.

Comment: Thanks..So the sentence is grammatically correct?

Comment: Correctness is relative to context.  The sentence isn't correct for formal writing, but it qualifies for the condensed nature of manuals for equipment.

Comment: So could you advise the correct one?

Comment: At the very least, add a comma after "on" to avoid the attraction of "on" for "router."  Again, what's considered correct depends on the context.  If you're rewriting the manual, it will up to you to decide the level of formality, and you certainly wouldn't rewrite just one instruction.  If you're repeating the instruction out loud, it won't be natural without adding the words I supplied in [brackets].